# About the ‘exist for each’ ‘exist for every’

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I have a problem in understanding the description ‘exist for each’ and ‘exist for every’.

This is a question from weak convergence.

Prove: Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $B$ be a dense subset of dual space $X^*$. If a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ is bounded , and if $\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ exists for each $x^* \in B$, then $\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ exists for all $x^*$ in $X^*$.

In my opinion, the first ‘if $\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ exists for each $x^* \in B$’ means real or complex number sequence $\{x^*(x_n)\}$ converges, but for different $x^* \in B$, the limit maybe different.

‘$\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ exists for all $x^*$ in $X^*$’ should mean the same, (the limit exists but could be different), because even if the weak limit is unique in any normed linear space, the limit of the value  $x^*(x_n)$ might not be the same.

Am I wrong here? I am not a native English speaker, so I would like to know the difference between these two words in math book.

I am also confused about the notation ‘$\lim_n x^*(x_n) $’. Does it mean the limit of real or complex number, or the weak limit of $x_n$? I think it should be the number.

Comment: I think your reading is correct. I think the proposition is basically saying that if we have that a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and $B$ a dense subspace of $X^*$ such that for all $\phi\in B$ $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(x_n)$ exists, then for any $\psi\in X^*$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\psi(x_n)$ exists.

Comment: @memerson Thank you so much!

Comment: I agree with @memerson, but I would characterize this as a case of trying to determine the author's *intended meaning*, because the two phrasings *actually mean* (in virtually all mathematical writing) the same thing. I wonder why the author didn't just write something like "if $\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ exists for each $x^* \in B$, then all the values of $\lim_n x^*(x_n)$ are the same", since the conclusion isn't about existence but instead the conclusion states a property of the objects whose existence is already assumed.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you so much. This is a question from the book. And I think it just asks me to prove the existence.